# convert curl command line to Perl WWW::Curl or LWP

Tags: perl, curl, lwp

I'm trying to replicate the following command line curl:

```
curl -F file=@myfile.csv 'https://myserver/api/import/data_save.html'
```

Does anyone have an example in either www::curl or lwp perhaps?  I have been trying all day and it's not even worth me posting my tries at this point, it would only confuse things.  Thank you!!!

Comment: "How do I do X?" questions are much easier to answer than "how can translate X?" because an exact translation is usually next to impossible, and rarely required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking how to submit a form with a file field named `file` populated with the contents of file `myfile.csv`.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $response = $ua->post('https://myserver/api/import/data_save.html',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Content => [
      file => [ 'myfile.csv' ],
   ],
);

die($response->status_line)
   if !$response->is_success;
```

The arguments to `$ua->post` are documented in [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Request::Common).

Comment: Really great feedback and answers.  I'm sorry for my generality or vagueness, I didn't know enough to even realize I was being that way.  Now I get it, I learned a lot and this really helps!

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's unpack what that curl command actually does, because `-F` implies a lot.

1. It sets the HTTP method of the request to POST.
2. It sets the Content-Type of the request to multipart/form-data.
3. It composes a MIME multipart request body with the form metadata indicating that the "file" input is being provided from a file named "myfile.csv", as well as a part containing the actual file contents.

Here's how to replicate that using WWW::Curl:

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use WWW::Curl::Form;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
my $form = WWW::Curl::Form->new;

$form->formaddfile('myfile.csv', 'file', "multipart/form-data");

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myserver/api/import/data_save.html');
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $form);
my $response = $curl->perform;
```

But LWP is probably easier; see ikegami's answer.

Comment: curl is faster. LWP is more portable. The curl module maybe *looks* a bit harder, but I don't think it actually *is* harder.

Comment: Certainly, neither is as easy as the `curl` command-line version.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only reason you might prefer WWW::Curl is that you're already familiar with the libcurl API from another language.

Comment: It's much much faster than LWP, and it supports doing requests in parallel. We used Net::Curl at my job for these reasons. It was even faster than LWP when emulating (the parts we needed of) LWP's interface!